# 2 Step Authentication for admin URL

Tags: magento-1.9, admin, security, password

I want to add 2 step Authentication to an admin back end URL to my clients online Magento shop. I don't want to use a google app authentication or a phone app/sms system. I want a master Username/Password for the first step then my usual admin accounts.

I've been googling for a while but can't find anything except for SMS/App authentication, is there some other way I'm missing?

Comment: I think OTP is semple and easiest way for authentication but there are a lot of authentication way in magento like https://amasty.com/magento-two-factor-authentication.html    and https://github.com/magento-hackathon/Magento-Two-factor-Authentication  or https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/yubikey-authentification-for-admin-logins.html  etc

Comment: Is there a way to do this without a Magento addon. Example: when you try to log into your home router/modem you are given a grey box to input credentials before you are allowed on the page.

Comment: there are a lot of way in php for security you can create your custom magento module

Comment: Have you got a link to any documentation I can look at? I've tried googling for a while but it keeps leading me to SMS/app authentication or Magento addons :-/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It seems you want to add a `.htaccess` directory protection.

Ad there is no *real* admin folder, you need to work around this:

```
SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI "^/admin/" ADMIN

AuthType Basic
AuthName "Magento Admin"
AuthUserFile /path/to/.htpasswd
Require valid-user

Satisfy any
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
Deny from env=ADMIN
```

Just add the usernames + passwords in the `.htpasswd` file and your're good to go.

You may also want to think of a solution like this where only certain IPs are allowed to access your admin URL:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/admin/(.*)$
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^111.112.113.114$ #your IP
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [F,L]
```

Comment: Thankyou Anna, just what I was after! IP and .htpasswd both worked perfectly!

Answer (score 4):

it's an old topic but I was looking for something like that and found it

first, thanks Anna for your answer, it helped me

but I see 2 problems:

1. leading ^ => /admin/ will be protected but /index.php/admin/admin/ won't be
2. trailing / => /admin/ will be protected but /admin won't be

so I use "/admin" instead (except I don't use "admin", see below)

so yes, frontend URL containing "/admin" will be caught
but remember that we are talking of the "admin" token only if you chose to let "admin" as identifier to your admin panel

you should change this identifier and put something harder to find and that you won't get in frontend

and code for Apache 2.4:

```
SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI "/[your admin identifier here]" ADMIN
AuthType basic
AuthName "Restricted Access"
AuthUserFile [path to your .htpasswd here]
<RequireAny>
    <RequireAll>
        Require env ADMIN
        Require valid-user
    </RequireAll>
    <RequireAll>
        Require not env ADMIN
        Require all granted
    </RequireAll>
</RequireAny>
```

Comment: .htaccess login popup is coming but if i click on Cancel button then still it is logging successfully. what should i do ?